# Correct way of making sharpe optimized portfolio?

Tags: portfolio-management, portfolio-optimization, sharpe-ratio

I have monthly returns of about 977 securities of past 10 years.

If I keep the returns as it is i.e. I do not multiply by 100 and keep the returns as 0.1, 0.2 , -0.3, 1.2

then I get different results in the securities shortlisted if I have used returns that are multiplied by 100 i.e. 10, 20, -30, 120

If I used 100x multiplied returns I get more than 290 securities out of 977 shortlisted and if I use without the 100x multiple I get only 4 securities.

Not sure what is the correct method to apply sharpe optimization model. I was expecting not to concentrated and not to diversified portfolio.

Code:

```
library(RCurl)
library(readxl)
library(lubridate)
library(quantmod)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library(zoo)
library(data.table)
library(xlsx)
library(plotly)


stocksDataPath <- "Monthly_All_Stocks"

totalPer = 100

#Rf = 100 * 0.00027      #Daily
#Rf = 100 * 0.001302     #Weekly
#Rf = 100 * 0.07   #Yearly
Rf =100 * 0.005654 #Monthly 

stocksList <- read.csv("topLiquidScrips.csv")
stocksList[nrow(stocksList)+1,1] = "^NSEI"

#market index (nifty 50)
n50 <- read.csv(paste(stocksDataPath,   "\\^NSEI.csv", sep = "" ))

n50$Ret <- 100 *n50$Ret 

inds <- 1
stocksRetData <- list()

# Read Stocks Return Data
for (i in 1:nrow(stocksList)){
  
  d <- read.csv(paste(stocksDataPath, "\\", stocksList[i,1] , ".csv", sep="") )
  
  d$Ret <- 100 * d$Ret
  
  if (nrow(d)>=totalPer){  
    
    d$Name = stocksList[i,1]
  
    d <- tail(d,totalPer)
  
    stocksRetData[[inds]] <- d
    
    inds <- inds + 1
    
  }
}


RM <- tail(n50$Ret, totalPer)

CALCData <- data.frame(
  StockName = as.character(),
  AriMean = as.numeric(),
  Beta = as.numeric(),
  Alpha = as.numeric(),
  Variance = as.numeric(),
  StdDev = as.numeric(),
  SysRisk = as.numeric(),
  UnSysRisk = as.numeric(),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

for (i in 1:length(stocksRetData)){
  
  betaVal = cov(RM,stocksRetData[[i]]$Ret)/var(RM)
  Ri = mean(stocksRetData[[i]]$Ret)
  
  
  CALCData <- rbind(CALCData,
                
        data.frame(
          StockName = stocksRetData[[i]]$Name[1],
          AriMean = Ri,
          Beta = betaVal,
          Alpha =  Ri - (mean(RM)*betaVal),
          Variance = var(stocksRetData[[i]]$Ret),
          StdDev =StdDev(stocksRetData[[i]]$Ret),
          SysRisk = StdDev(RM) * betaVal,
          UnSysRisk = StdDev(stocksRetData[[i]]$Ret) - (StdDev(RM) * betaVal)
        )
                    
  )
  
}


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------



CALCData$MarketRiskPremium = CALCData$AriMean - Rf
CALCData$TreynorRatio = CALCData$MarketRiskPremium/CALCData$Beta

# Sort by Tryenor ratio in descending order
CALCData <-CALCData[order(-CALCData$TreynorRatio),]
CALCData$CVal = (CALCData$MarketRiskPremium * CALCData$Beta) / CALCData$UnSysRisk

CALCData$CUMSUMCVal <- cumsum(CALCData$CVal)

CALCData$BetaSqrVar = (CALCData$Beta ^2) / CALCData$UnSysRisk
CALCData$CUMSUMBetaSqrVal = cumsum(CALCData$BetaSqrVar)

CALCData$Cutoff = ( var(RM)*CALCData$CUMSUMCVal ) / (1 + var(RM) + CALCData$CUMSUMBetaSqrVal ) 

CALCData$Diff =CALCData$Cutoff- lag(CALCData$Cutoff,1)
CALCData$Diff[is.na(CALCData$Diff)] <- 0

CALCData <- subset(CALCData,CALCData$Diff > 0)

CVal = tail(CALCData$Cutoff, 1)

#Z=(C5/D5)*((E5/C5)-$K$1)
CALCData$ZVal = (CALCData$Beta / CALCData$UnSysRisk)/ ( (CALCData$MarketRiskPremium / CALCData$Beta) - CVal)

sumofZVal = sum(CALCData$ZVal)

CALCData$InvProportion = 100 * round(CALCData$ZVal /sum(CALCData$ZVal),3)

#write.csv(CALCData,paste("CALCData_", stocksDataPath ,"_", totalPer, "_Period_", "_", gsub(":","", Sys.time()),".csv", sep=""), row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Are you solving your portfolio scheme numerically? Or are you applying a closed-form solution? Could you please provide some code related to your problem? :-)

Comment: @Pleb added code for reference

Comment: If you change the units for the stock returns, you must change the units for the Risk Free rate also. Then the solution should be exactly the same.

Comment: @noob2 I did change it